# How to upgrading to new release automatically or download the release iso once it's released?

Tags: upgrade

All of you know that within few hours, Ubuntu 14.04 is going to be released.

What can I do to upgrade my system automatically when Ubuntu 14.04 is arrived?

And also What can I do to download a single Ubuntu 14.04 desktop-64-bit iso file or all the trusty images automatically when it was arrived(available for download)?

Comment: Open up your computer at 2.30 AM IST ;-) .. jokes apart. You can upgrade to beta now. There won't be much changes on last day.

Answer (score 4):

I extremely **recommend against**. Upgrading from a version to the next can take several hours, block your system, wait for your intervention, be interrupted by power loss, leave your system unbootable, etc.

When upgrading you should make sure that you have the time and a backup plan in case something go wrong. The upgrades to the next version are not automatic for this reason, *there is several things that can go wrong*.

Comment: I agree with @Braiam. I have done many upgrades over the years I have used Ubuntu. I can't remember a time, when the upgrade completed without any user interaction. There is always one or more config files I had changed, that the upgrade wants me to look over and decide whether to replace of retain.

Answer (score 1):

Better version, with python3. Slightly more efficient and checks every 2 minutes. Just have it run in a `screen` process

**dload.py**

```
import subprocess
import time
import http.client
def exists(site, path):
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(site)
    conn.request('HEAD', path)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    conn.close()
    return response.status == 200

while 5>0:
    if(exists("releases.ubuntu.com:80","/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso")):
         print("Downloading")
         subprocess.call(['wget', 'http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso'])
         break
    time.sleep(2*60)
```

**Running it:**

1. Copy the above into a file called dload.py
2. Open a terminal and type `screen`
3. type in `python3 ./dload.py`

Answer (score -2):

Hm, hard one. I guess you could make a script that tries to do a wget to the location where the ISO will probably arrive once it's released:

`wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

You might need to change the ISO name to the architecture of your system (amd64 or i386)

Just script it and put it on a cron job every 15 minutes or so. :P

Comment: The problem with this is that once it downloads, it will keep downloading a new copy every 15 minutes.